# Package Remotion.Linq 2.0.2 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, .net-core, .net-core-rc2

This one is driving me crazy.

If I create a .NET Core Console App in VS2015, making no changes it builds and runs as expected.

When I add Entity Framework RC2 by adding a dependency in project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [ "dnxcore50" ]
    }
  }
}
```

then restoring packages gives the following errors:

```
Package Ix-Async 1.2.5 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0

Package Remotion.Linq 2.0.2 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0
```

This is expected as a work around is required as per the article here: https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/rc1-rc2-upgrade.html#using-imports-in-project-json

Where it describes adding a portable profile as an import:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [ "dnxcore50", "portable-net45+win8" ]
    }
  }
```

This resolves the issue with the Ix-Async but does not fix the issue with Remotion.Linq i.e. I am still seeing this error.

```
Package Remotion.Linq 2.0.2 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0
```

I tried everything I can think of (different profiles, different project types, clearing caches) and even uninstalled, reinstalled everything several times. Short of re-building my PC I've run of ideas...

Comment: I can't reproduce this. After modifying the project.json, package restore works fine for me. The only thing I can think of: do you have the latest version of .Net Core Tools installed in VS?

Comment: Thanks svick. Not surprised it works - think I'll need to start with a clean windows environment!

Comment: The same error here

Comment: Windows 10 or Powershell not being version 5 issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a VM and installed tools etc as before. I opened and built the solution successfully. So it was not my project or installs.

So on my PC I created a new Windows account. I opened and built the solution successfully on that account.

Assumption is that something is configured or cached against my other account. I deleted as much cache data as I could (in AppData etc) and yet the solution would still not build.

So the answer is, don't waste hours of your time trying to find out what the problem is, but use a fresh windows account! Not ideal obviously....